# save attachments to database and Rails application public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

I am new to ROR and learning it.I am using Rails 2.3.5. I have a form where I can attach multiple files. I need to save these attachments in my db and also in a directory in my application directory. I dont want to use paperclip plugin as I need to learn File system as well as how to create dir and save these attachments into it. So any references/tutorials would be highly appreciated. Please help. 
When I submit the form I get the params in the console as

```
Processing ReminderPluginController#create_reminder (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-05 19:52:14) [POST]
  Parameters: {"reminder"=>{"subject"=>"Hello", "email"=>"", "body"=>"<p>My first thing</p>"}, "attachments"=>[#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131005-8107-o8osmj-0>, #<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131005-8107-1n1k7pz-0>], "controller"=>"reminder_plugin", "select_batch"=>{"batch"=>"2"}, "recipients"=>"20", "select_department"=>{"department"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send", "authenticity_token"=>"pKT8//ESD5SWvSuelVpOiHw3k30RxrqDOODckUToURs=", "action"=>"create_reminder"}
```

But I have no idea about creating directory and saving attachments in it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of curiosity, why are you learning on Rails 2.3.5 when Rails is now up to version 4? Believe me, there is a world of difference.

But on the question at hand, I think you will find these references useful:

- [File Uploading using Rails](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm)
- [Store file in directory tmp on heroku Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552937/store-file-in-directory-tmp-on-heroku-rails) on StackOverflow. That's a Heroku-specific question but the basic idea is the same.

Hope that helps.