# Heroku syncing with Git automatically resulting in loss of files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, heroku

I deployed an app in Heroku using Github, and the code works fine.

I have a piece of code which creates `uploads` directory in the root and puts in all uploaded files. I was able to retrieve the files without any trouble after uploading. However after an hour or so (perhaps after the dyno sleeps and restarts) the files were all gone.

A file (with a random file name) which was cached in git sneaked into the repository (although I have gitignored the directory) and not until I found the same exact file (with that exact name) on heroku server, I understood the problem is not that files are being deleted, but rather it's being synced with my repository that's causing the problem.

How do I prevent this from happening?

PS: I made sure Automatic deployment is off in heroku and checked again. Same results. Google doesn't give any relevant results for "files lost heroku" or "prevent automatic sync heroku github" ://

Answer (score 1):

> Heroku uses an ephemeral filesystem. Local filesystem is only accessible to a single dyno, and once the dyno is stopped, restarted, or moved, all files on the local filesystem are destroyed.

In fact, I could not even see the uploads folder though heroku console even though I was able to download the file from the controller using `send_file`.

[image]

[image]

This also means that the files were lost not because the dyno synced with `Github` but because of the nature of the dynos and filesystem itself, that the **dyno will not find the folder once restarted**.

Credits: Benjamin Manns' Source: [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18553063/3125070)